# Cannot convert arraylist to string array

Tags: c#

```
    public string[] getallTourID()
    {
        ArrayList TourIDs = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Tour o in TourCollections) //TourCollections is an arraylist of tour objects
        {
            TourIDs.Add(o.getID); //ID is a string from the tour object
        }
        return TourIDs.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

Hi, I needed help with this issue where I cannot convert the `arraylist` to `string array`. The error says that:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Array to string[], an explicit
>   conversion exist

The problem comes from the `ToArray()` function. May I know what is the issue?

Will really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Solution 1:

```
string[] array = TourIDs.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
```

Solution 2:

```
String[] array= (String[])TourIDs.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Comment: Then why down vote ?, there is many ways to cast that list to string array but I have posted what he want as his snippet code, Down vote with no reason because it accepted as answer ?!!!

Comment: Please let me know why ?

Comment: downvotes occur because people think it is not the best way to solve OP's problem. (btw, I didn't downvote your answer)

Comment: @Pac0, Yes as I said there are some ways to do that, but I posted solution which more closer to his code which does not mean we don't know about Linq or modern way , If I updated my question then people also think I copied their code yes???? for this reason I didn't, here to get upvote and post solution must be fast and focus on posted time, edited details and etc...

Comment: This may not the best way to solve the OP's problem, but it is  valid answer and it is not deserved for downvote. Downvotes are for incorrect answers and really bad tries!

Comment: @Aria I don't think your answer deserves any downvote either, but at the end it's just the opinion of members who see the question and its answers.

Comment: @Pac0 Thank you for your attention , I accepted it anyway it is just their opinion and we can't don't let they to avoid down vote.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thank you, yes this is not incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need a raw `ArrayList` collection, you should be making it a `List<Tour>` and then extract the Id's:

as such:

```
return TourCollections.Select(t => t.getId).ToArray();
```

if for some reason you cannot do that then use [OfType](https://www.dotnetperls.com/oftype) to only return objects from a source collection that are of a certain type.

```
return TourIDs.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve what you want, you can simply **use a simple linq query** and avoid any intermediate explicit array / list :

```
using System.Linq;

public string[] getallTourID()
{
    return TourCollections.Select(o => o.getId).ToArray();
}
```

---

You *could* actually do litteraly what you want by casting the result of ToArray(typeof(string)) `as string[]`, but the usual modern "Csharpic" way to do it is the linq projection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
  TourIDs.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
```

For further info, Refer https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-arraylist-array